# Short blank screen a few seconds after login

Tags: ubuntu, x11, intel-graphics, unity

I am using `Ubuntu 15.10` with `unity` on a Lenovo Thinkpad T460s laptop.

**A few seconds after I login my laptop screen as well as the external monitor go blank** (i.e., black) for a very **short time**.

I managed to trace back the following **log entries** in Xorg.0.log which were written exactly when the screens go blank:

```
[ 18772.673] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1920x1200@60.0 on HDMI2 using pipe 1, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
[ 18773.291] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1600x900@60.0 on eDP1 using pipe 0, position (1920, 106), rotation normal, reflection none
```

Here is my **system configuration** (Lenovo Thinkpad T460s):

```
$ uname -a
Linux impetus 4.2.0-34-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 10 22:13:01 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ glxinfo
[...]
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Skylake ULT GT2 
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 11.0.2
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
[...]
```

- Processor:  4x Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz
- Graphics:   Intel HD Graphics 520

**Question:**
Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Please do not hesitate to ask if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

I was lookiing for a solution to this to, found this. seems to work for me.
open a terminal and execute this..

```
xset s off && xset -dpms
```